# Reducing "for" comprehension duplication

Tags: macros, clojure, code-duplication, for-comprehension

In my answer to [Clojure For Comprehension example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11530574/151650), there is some duplication that I would like to remove:

```
(def all-letters (map char (range 65 90)))
(defn kw [& args] (keyword (apply str args)))
(concat
  (for [l all-letters] (kw l))
  (for [l all-letters l2 all-letters] (kw l l2))
  (for [l all-letters l2 all-letters l3 all-letters] (kw l l2 l3)))
```

I would like to remove the "for" duplication. I have written the following macro:

```
(defmacro combine [times]
 (let [symbols (repeatedly times gensym)
       for-params (vec (interleave symbols (repeat 'all-letters)))]
    `(for ~for-params (kw ~@symbols))))
```

Which works with:

```
 (concat (combine 1) (combine 2) (combine 3))
```

But if I try:

```
 (for [i (range 1 4)] (combine i))
```

I get:

```
CompilerException java.lang.ClassCastException: clojure.lang.Symbol cannot be cast to java.lang.Number, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:177)
```

What is going on? Is there a better way of removing the duplication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `combine` is a macro that gets expanded at compile time. When you try to expand on a symbol `i` it fails, because it is designed to take a number (times). `i` is just a symbol at compile time, it only evaluates to numeric values at runtime.

I'd suggest rewriting `combine` to be a function rather than a macro: you don't really need macros here and functions are frequently more convenient (as in this case!).

Here's a recursive combine that probably does roughly what you want:

```
(defn combine
    ([times] (combine times nil))
    ([times letters]
      (if (<= times 0)
        (keyword (apply str letters))
        (flatten (for [l all-letters] (combine (dec times) (cons l letters)))))))
```

Comment: Is it because "for" is also a macro?

Comment: the `for` isn't what is causing the problem, it is a macro but it has the effect you would expect at runtime - the real problem is the `i` which is a symbol at compile time when used in the `combine` macro. Added a few more explanatory notes.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your macro such that the `concat` becomes part of the macro, such shown below. But I agree with Mikera that it is better to have a function.

```
(defmacro combine [start end]
 `(concat
      ~@(for [i (range start end)]
          (let [symbols (repeatedly i gensym)
             for-params (vec (interleave symbols (repeat 'all-letters)))]
          `(for ~for-params (kw ~@symbols))))))

user=> (combine 1 2)
(:A :B :C :D :E :F :G :H :I :J :K :L :M :N :O :P :Q :R :S :T :U :V :W :X :Y)
```