# Circular definition in Clojure

Tags: clojure

Here is an example:

```
(defn f1 [] (lazy-seq (cons 0 (f2))))
(defn f2 [] (lazy-seq (cons 1 (f3))))
(defn f3 [] (lazy-seq (cons 2 (f1))))
```

In Haskell, the equivalent of the above example would produce a lazy sequence of [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, ...], but in clojure this would lead to a CompilerException because `f2` could not be resolved.

Is there any way around this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Must Clojure circular data structures involve constructs like ref?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11568036/must-clojure-circular-data-structures-involve-constructs-like-ref)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use `declare` to create forward declarations

```
user> (declare f1) 
#'user/f1
user> (declare f2)
#'user/f2
user> (declare f3)
#'user/f3
```

or as Thumbnail points out:

```
user> (declare f1 f2 f3)
#'user/f3
```

works as well

```
user> (defn f1 [] (lazy-seq (cons 0 (f2))))
#'user/f1
user> (defn f2 [] (lazy-seq (cons 1 (f3))))
 #'user/f2
user> (defn f3 [] (lazy-seq (cons 2 (f1))))
#'user/f3
```

then you get your recursive lazy sequence:

```
user> (take 20 (f3))
(2 0 1 2 0 1 2 0 1 2 0 1 2 0 1 2 0 1 2 0)
```

Comment: neet I like that better as well, I'll edit to use that instead, thanks

Comment: It was my habit with C++ to declare *all* the entities at the top of the header file. Then you can define them in any order you like, however mutually recursive they are. I see people doing the same with clojure namespaces. Perhaps a namespace should have a syntactic presence, then the compiler could do it for us.

Comment: It's tough with the current one-pass compiler design, and a two pass compiler is hard to reconcile with the possibility of side-effecting macro expansion, amongst other issues

Answer (score 8):

If you just want to produce the lazy sequence, you can define a bunch of mutually recursive functions *locally* using `letfn`:

```
(letfn [(f1 [] (lazy-seq (cons 0 (f2))))
        (f2 [] (lazy-seq (cons 1 (f3))))
        (f3 [] (lazy-seq (cons 2 (f1))))]
  (f1))

=> (0 1 2 0 1 2 0 1 2 0 1 2 0 1 2 0 1 2 0 1 2 ...
```